# How to do something when control is appear in document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How it possible by javascript? I could't find event like:

```
$(.check-icon).on('loaded', function(){...});
```

Comment: By *control*, do you mean an image?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Not document. Only one item on page.

Comment: Control isn't image. It's link.

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. document.ready will be called when all the elements have been loaded. so your control too will be loaded. can you explain it by an example.

Comment: One time is loaded "edit" link, after clicking on this link showing download image and loaded "check" link. After loaded "check" link download image must stay hidden.

Comment: why don't you write on edit link click check link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(.check-icon).on('load', function(){...});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you meant after `DOM` got ready in your `document`

you can use this. [Check here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ---code here
});
```